# Convert gds file into text format using gds2text script

Tags: python-2.7, gdscript

How I can to read any gdsii file in python,or  Convert gds file into text format using gds2text script?

Comment: Please add some code. Also please explain what you have already tried.

Comment: I have a some *.gds file (for example nand.gds file for nand layout) and I need to convert the file to txt.I use python-gdsii 0.2.1library [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-gdsii), this package also includes scripts that can be used to convert binary GDS file to a simple text format (gds2txt).

Comment: I tried use the scrpt using command propt...for example python gds2txt.py nand.gds

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a C/C++ compiler you might consider using gds2gdt and gdt2gds to read and/or write GDSII using any language/shell of your choice. GDSII is a stream of records each of which is represented in a single line of compact GDT format text. For instance:

```
p{10 w1.2 xy(41.2 17.1 41.2 33.9)}
```

is a two-point path on layer 10 with a width of 1.2. you can run these programs externally or call them within your program similar to reading/writing a text file.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/gds2/

Answer (score 0):

I created gdsast python package specifically to be able to look at the GDS file content as data tree (same as JSON), analyse and manipulate it easily.

For your purpose just do:

```
from gdsast import *

with open("some.gds","rb") as f:
    gds = gds_read(f)
```

then you could save it into JSON with:

```
import json

with open("some_gds.json","wt") as f:
    json.dump(gds, f, indent=2)
```

and finally you could read result JSON file as text.